# Using Apparition with Capybara, browser_logger is not producing output

Tags: rspec, capybara, apparition

I'm trying to move away from Poltergeist/PhantomJS through the use of Apparition.

Configuring the driver is working as expected, with the exception of output of Chrome logs.

This is my driver configuration:

```
Capybara.register_driver :apparition do |app|
    options = {
      debug: false,
      headless: true,
      browser_logger: STDOUT,
      timeout: 3,
      ignore_https_errors: true,
      screen_size: [1920, 1080],
      skip_image_loading: false,
      js_errors: false,
      headers: {
        "User-Agent" => "Apparition"
      }
    }
    Capybara::Apparition::Driver.new(app, options)
end
```

I expected to see Chrome's console output mixed in with Capybara's, but absolutely nothing is being produced.

Is my syntax incorrect?

Thanks,
Shaun

Answer (score 0):

If I do e.g. `console.log("foo")` in JavaScript, our Capybara + Apparition tests will output that during the run. So, yes, Capybara + Apparition normally has that behaviour.

Try removing all those options and see how you do.

Here's a self-contained example of `console.log` outputting stuff. Save it as `example.rb` and run it with `ruby example.rb`. (Example code mostly from https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/issues/2256#issuecomment-542238546.)

```
require "bundler/inline"

gemfile do
  source "https://rubygems.org"
  gem "capybara"
  gem "puma"
  gem "apparition"
end

require "capybara/apparition"
require "capybara/dsl"

html = DATA.read
app = proc { |env| [200, { "Content-Type" => "text/html" }, [html] ] }

Capybara.register_driver :apparition do |app|
  Capybara::Apparition::Driver.new(app,
  )
end

sess = Capybara::Session.new(:apparition, app)
sess.visit("/")

__END__

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Hello!</title>
    <script>
      console.log("hi");
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Hello world.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

This example will still output the log even if I add all the options you use, though, so there may be something else going on.